# A problem in calculus mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

Hi tried to solve this for hours, any idea how to approach this question:
prove for every $x>0$
$$2x\times\arctan(x)>\ln(1+x^2)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define for $\;x\ge0\;$

$$f(x)=2x\arctan x-\log(1+x^2)\implies f'(x)=2\arctan x\stackrel{\color{red}{x>0}}>0$$

Thus, the function's monotonic increasing and

$$f(0)=0\implies \forall\,x>0\;,\;\;f(x)>0\iff 2x\arctan x>\log(1+x^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\tan^{-1}x > \dfrac{\ln(1+x^2)}{2x}, x > 0$. Differentiate both sides and consider appropriate function and prove it increasing.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$ 2x\arctan x = 2x\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2} $$
and:
$$ \log(1+x^2) = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{2t\, dx}{1+t^2}$$
and since for any $t\in (0,x)$ we have $t<x$, it follows that $\log(1+x^2)<2x\arctan x.$